Setting RGB channels to 247 in Blender for TurboSquid
I'm attempting to create an image with RGB values of 247, 247, 247 in Blender. It set to 247 in RGB channels. However, when I save it as a PNG, it shows up as 255 for RGB in both Photopea and Photoshop. In the Compositing tab, the Render Layers node (image) is connected to the Alpha Over (Image), which is then linked to the Composite (Image). What can I do to resolve this issue?

enter image description here






Which render engine are you actually using? Eevee plor cycles? Please fix the tags.

If you set it to 247, it is 247 times 1, while 1 is white in Blender. For more details see Lutzi's answer. @Leander The render engine is completely irrelevant for this issue, both would produce a similar (not desired) result with this color values. By the way, the screenshot shows it's EEVEE.

@TheLabCat The screenshots provided with the question show that Transparent is enabled.

Color representation
RGB channels in Blender are represented as a float value in the range 0-1. The 247 and 255 values you are talking about is an integer value in the range 0-255.
In your case, if the color you want is (247,247,247) in the range 0-255, then you could use either the hexadecimal value, or an approximation in the 0-1 range. You can use Photoshop to find the hexadecimal value, or online tools.

Hexadecimal : #F7F7F7 (best solution as it is exactly 247)
Float : (0.930105, 0.930112, 0.930111). This isn't a good way of doing it if you already have the hexadecimal value. I got it by entering the hexa in Blender and look at the channels.

Color managment
Everything above is true if the color managment of your blend file is set to Standard. In this color space, each color inside your scene will be exactly the same colors as in your final render. This may seem obvious but ...
There are other color managments, used for example to represent a more realistic behavior of colors and light. This is used for photorealistic rendering, as an example. The default color managment is AgX.
Why would Blender use a 0-1 range ?
The range 0-255 is for 8bit colors, meaning each channel has $2^8 = 256$ possible values. Almost all domestic display devices are also 8bit colors.
By using a float value 0-1, the bit depth can be way higher than 8, which is widely use for visual effects, post-processing, theater projection, ...
Blender doesn't really use a 0-1 range
Blender let's you go above 1 with your channels. You can think of it as overexposed colors : colors with a stronger intensity. This is what you did in your question, you set the channels to 247.0. You can totally do that in Blender, but you're way beyond the maximum #FFFFFF white you deal with in image processing software.

This is true, but only part of the answer. There needs to be a mention of color management (at least the difference between the default Filmic/AGX vs Standard).

I don't see any issue, the color managment is already set to standard.

Yes, but the OP didn't mention it so it's safe to assume it might not have been a decision made consciously for that issue, and we can also assume that people encountering the issue and finding this topic might not know about this in the first place so it would be a good small-but-impactful addition to an answer.

@Lauloque Since Blender nowadays is by default not using Standard, it let's me assume it was a conscious decision, perhaps because it was already mentioned somewhere else that this might be necessary if you want to get "correct" colors while he was seeking help on this problem. So it's not necessary mentioning here again if the answer works as is. Or as I was just "educated" by someone here: You don't have to put everything in a single answer as it makes it less clear and comprehensible.
